# Curl several urls in a script

Tags: python, curl, dns

First off, I'm a complete noob to scripting.  I've look and tried numerous snippets of code for what I'm trying to do, but no luck yet.
I want to create a simple python or shell script that will visit several urls consecutive.
I do not need any information returned.  The Only purpose of the script is for DNS resolution to take place.  The reason I'm doing this is when the DNS lookup traverses a security tool of mine, the tool will tell me if its a malicious domain or not based on a db.  Currently, I"m doing this a very manual way - via the browser or terminal using curl one at a time.  I would like to simply drop 5 - 10 domains into a script and run it so that a DNS lookup would take place for each domain/url.
From Terminal on my Mac, I can simply curl this, but a script would be fantastic.  Is there a simple script to do this?  Thanks for helping a noob out.

Answer (score 0):

What does your `curl` call look like? You can use `subprocess.call()` to run a shell command from a python script.

Here's an example of downloading two images:

**script.py**

```
import subprocess

data = [
    ("homer.jpg",
     "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Homer_Simpson_2006.png"),
    ("bart.jpg",
     "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png")
]
for datum in data:
    subprocess.call(["curl", "-o", datum[0], datum[1]])
```

The `subprocess.call()` function takes a list of arguments so in my example it translates to running the following commands from a terminal:

- `curl -o "homer.jpg" "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Homer_Simpson_2006.png"`
- `curl -o "bart.jpg" "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png"`

Comment: I've also heard of [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) but I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and you've got me much closer.  Let's say the url is simply just www.nfl.com or www.cnn.com?  I tried just list those urls (cnn, nfl) but it doesn't work.  Thanks again!

Comment: If you're still working on this, I can take a look at your code if you want (you can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or something).